# Android - Eclipse suddenly stopped asking me what emulator I want to use, and does not show new things in the emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am having a weird issue where, whenever I try to run a new build to the emulator, the system no longer asks me what Emulator I want to use, and simply builds an old version of the code, no matter what the current changes are.

Would anyone know why this happens? I already rebooted twice, and cleaned the project, but can not get the latest code to build on the emulator.

Advice appreciated :)

Comment: A couple things to try: At the shell, `adb uninstall com.my.package.name` and possibly `adb kill-server;adb start-server`. "Launch Operation" under Eclipse prefs -> Run/Debug -> Launching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Run --> Run Configurations... --> Target and make sure that 'Always prompt to pick device' is marked